# Invalid _id error handling with JavaScript with Mongoose #4897

Tags: javascript, mongoose, error-handling

Is there anyone that knows how to fix this problem??
I hope someone can help me with this. When I run in develep mode I get all error without the updateTour. I only get the old object do not get the error that is generate when name is to short and the other invalid errors. But when I run in production mode I only get the error status and the same problem with updateTour.

Thanks

errorController.js

```
const AppError = require('./../utils/appError');

const handleCastErrorDB = err => {
  const message = `Invalid ${err.path}: ${err.value}.`;
  return new AppError(message, 400);
};

const handleDuplicateFieldsDB = err => {
  const value = err.errmsg.match(/(["'])(\\?.)*?\1/)[0];
  console.log(value);

  const message = `Duplicate field value: ${value}. Please use another value!`;
  return new AppError(message, 400);
};
const handleValidationErrorDB = err => {
  const errors = Object.values(err.errors).map(el => el.message);

  const message = `Invalid input data. ${errors.join('. ')}`;
  return new AppError(message, 400);
};

const sendErrorDev = (err, res) => {
  res.status(err.statusCode).json({
    status: err.status,
    error: err,
    message: err.message,
    stack: err.stack
  });
};

const sendErrorProd = (err, res) => {
  // Operational, trusted error: send message to client
  if (err.isOperational) {
    res.status(err.statusCode).json({
      status: err.status,
      message: err.message
    });

    // Programming or other unknown error: don't leak error details
  } else {
    // 1) Log error
    console.error('ERROR ', err);

    // 2) Send generic message
    res.status(500).json({
      status: 'error',
      message: 'Something went very wrong!'
    });
  }
};

module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  // console.log(err.stack);

  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.status = err.status || 'error';

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    sendErrorDev(err, res);
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    let error = { ...err };

    if (error.name === 'CastError') error = handleCastErrorDB(err);
    if (error.code === 11000) error = handleDuplicateFieldsDB(err);
    if (error._message === 'Tour validation failed')
      error = handleValidationErrorDB(err);

    sendErrorProd(error, res);
  }
};
```

tourController.js

```
 const Tour = require('../models/tourModel');
const APIFeatures = require('../utils/apiFeatures');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');

// const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

// const tours = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../dev-data/data/tours-simple.json`));

/**
 * Middleware sow you can get the five cheapest tours in the database
 * @param {*} req
 * @param {*} res
 * @param {*} next
 */

exports.aliasTopTours = (req, res, next) => {
  req.query.limit = '5';
  req.query.sort = '-ratingsAverage,price';
  req.query.fields = 'name,price,ratingsAverage,summary,difficulty';
  next();
};

/**
 * This method gets all the tours in the database
 * @param {*} req
 * @param {*} res
 *
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
exports.getAllTours = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  /**
   * Create a new Object of the APIFeatures
   */
  const features = new APIFeatures(Tour.find(), req.query)
    .filter()
    .sort()
    .limitFields()
    .paginate();

  // Get resalt from database
  const tours = await features.query;
  if(!tours){
    return next(new AppError('Couldn\'t find any tour in the database',404))
  }

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    requestedAt: req.requstTime,
    results: tours.length,
    data: {
      tours,
    },
  });
});

/**
 * Creates a new tour in the database
 * @param {*} req
 * @param {*} res
 */
exports.createTour = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      tour: newTour,
    },
  });
});
/**
 * Gets a single tour in  the database
 * @param {*} req
 * @param {*} res
 */
exports.getTour = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
   const tour = Tour.findById(req.params.id).then((tour) => {
    
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      requestedAt: req.requstTime,
      data: {
        tour,
      },
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    return next(new AppError('No tour found with that ID', 404))
  });
});

/**
 * Update a single tour in the database use the ID to find the tour and JSON object to update the tour
 * @param {*} req
 * @param {*} res
 */
exports.updateTour = catchAsync(async (req, res,next) => {
  Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
  }).then((tour) => {
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      requestedAt: req.requstTime,
      data: {
        tour,
      },
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    return next(new AppError('No tour found with that ID', 404))
  });
});
/**
 * Delete a single tour in  the database. Use the ID to find the tour and then deletes the object
 */
exports.deleteTour = catchAsync(async (req, res,next ) => {
  Tour.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id).then((tour) => {
    res.status(204).json({
      status: 'success',
      requestedAt: req.requstTime,
      data: {
        tour,
      },
    });
  });
});
/**
 * Calculate avg rating and avg price for all the tour in the database
 */
exports.getTourStatus = catchAsync(async (req, res,next) => {
  const stats = await Tour.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { ratingsAverage: { $gte: 4.5 } },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $toUpper: '$difficulty' },
        numTours: { $sum: 1 },
        numRatings: { $sum: '$ratingsQuantity' },
        avgRating: { $avg: '$ratingsAverage' },
        avgPrice: { $avg: '$price' },
        minPrice: { $min: '$price' },
        maxPrice: { $max: '$price' },
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: { avgPrice: 1 },
    },
    // {
    //   $match: { _id: { $ne: 'EASY' } }
    // }
  ]);

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      stats,
    },
  });
});

/**
 *The getMonthlyPlan shows how many tours that is for witch month
 *
 * @param {*} req
 * @param {*} res
 * @memberof tourController
 */
exports.getMonthlyPlan = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const year = req.params.year * 1;
    const plan = await Tour.aggregate([
      {
        $unwind: '$startDates',
      },
      {
        $match: {
          startDates: {
            $gte: new Date(`2023-01-01`),
            $lte: new Date(`2023-12-31`),
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { $month: '$startDates' },
          numTourStarts: { $sum: 1 },
          tours: { $push: '$name' },
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: { month: '$_id' },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: { numTourStarts: -1 },
      },
    ]);

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      results: plan.length,
      requestedAt: req.requstTime,
      data: {
        plan,
      },
    });  
});
```

I want the program to handel the error invalid _id
[image: Run in production mode]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it:

```
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
let error = { ...err };

// change error.name => error.kind, 'CastError' => 'ObjectId'
if (error.kind === 'ObjectId') error = handleCastErrorDB(err);
if (error.code === 11000) error = handleDuplicateFieldsDB(err);
if (error._message === 'Tour validation failed')
  error = handleValidationErrorDB(err);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).